# Controls on page are not displaying respective values based on drop down selection

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, drop-down-menu

I have a User Registration page through which new users can be registered.

As seen in the ASPX page below, i have a User Name drop down. On selection of any value in this dropdown, the details of that user are to be displayed in the respective controls. This is happening only for the User Name text box.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
```

```
<div>

    <table>

        <tr>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_UserName" runat="server" Text="User Name: " 
                    ForeColor="Black" CssClass="LabelStyles"></asp:Label>
            </td>

            <td class="style3">

                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_UserName" runat="server" 
                    onselectedindexchanged="UserName_Changed" AutoPostBack="True">
                </asp:DropDownList>

            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_tbUserName" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Text="User Name: " CssClass="LabelStyles"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="style3">
                <asp:TextBox ID="tb_UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Password" runat="server" Text="Password: " ForeColor="Black" CssClass="LabelStyles"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="style3">
                <asp:TextBox ID="tb_Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" 
                    ForeColor="Black"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_cnfrmPassword" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Text="Confirm Password: " CssClass="LabelStyles"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="style3">
                <asp:TextBox ID="tb_cnfrmPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Admin" runat="server" Text="Admin: " ForeColor="Black" CssClass="LabelStyles"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="style3">
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="YesNo_RadioButtonList" runat="server" Height="22px" 
                    RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="51px" ForeColor="Black">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">No</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </td>
```

Code behind for populating drop down

```
protected void Populate_ddlUserName()
    {

        dsRetrieveUserDetails = objLoginData.RetrieveUser();
        dtUser.Columns.Add("UserID");
        dtUser.Columns.Add("UserName");
        dtUser.Rows.Add("", "Select User");
        dtUser.Rows.Add("Add New", "Add New");

        int count = dsRetrieveUserDetails.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            dtUser.Rows.Add(dsRetrieveUserDetails.Tables[0].Rows[i]["UserID"].ToString() + "@" +
                dsRetrieveUserDetails.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Password"].ToString() + "@" + dsRetrieveUserDetails.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Admin"].ToString(), dsRetrieveUserDetails.Tables[0].Rows[i]["UserName"].ToString());
        }

        ddl_UserName.DataSource = dtUser;

        ddl_UserName.DataValueField = "UserID";
        ddl_UserName.DataTextField = "UserName";

        ddl_UserName.DataBind();
    }
```

Code behind for selected index changed

```
protected void UserName_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dsRetrieveUserDetails = objLoginData.RetrieveUser();

        if (ddl_UserName.SelectedItem.Text == "Add New")
        {
            //Displaying hidden controls
            lbl_tbUserName.Visible = true;
            tb_UserName.Visible = true;

            //Hiding unnecessary controls
            btn_delNo.Visible = false;
            btn_delYes.Visible = false;
            lbl_DeleteMsg.Visible = false;

            //Enabling&Disabling controls
            btn_Reset.Enabled = true;
            btn_Register.Enabled = true;
            btnDelete.Enabled = false;

            //Setting Values
            tb_UserName.Text = "";
            tb_Password.Text = "";
            tb_cnfrmPassword.Text = "";
            YesNo_RadioButtonList.ClearSelection();
        }

        else if (ddl_UserName.SelectedItem.Text == "Select User")
        {
            //Setting values
            tb_UserName.Text = "";
            tb_Password.Text = "";
            tb_cnfrmPassword.Text = "";
            YesNo_RadioButtonList.ClearSelection();

            //Disabling controls
            btn_Register.Enabled = false;
            btn_Reset.Enabled = false;
            btnDelete.Enabled = false;

            //Hiding unnecessary controls
            lbl_tbUserName.Visible = false;
            tb_UserName.Visible = false;
            lbl_DeleteMsg.Visible = false;
            btn_delNo.Visible = false;
            btn_delYes.Visible = false;
        }

        else
        {
            //Displaying some hidden controls
            lbl_tbUserName.Visible = true;
            tb_UserName.Visible = true;

            //Setting values
            tb_UserName.Text = ddl_UserName.SelectedItem.Text;

            //Enabling&Disabling controls
            btn_Register.Enabled = true;
            btn_Reset.Enabled = true;
            btnDelete.Enabled = true;

            //Hiding unnecessary controls
            lbl_DeleteMsg.Visible = false;
            btn_delYes.Visible = false;
            btn_delNo.Visible = false;

            string[] values = ddl_UserName.SelectedValue.Split('@');

            tb_Password.Text = values[1];
            tb_cnfrmPassword.Text = values[1];

            YesNo_RadioButtonList.SelectedIndex = YesNo_RadioButtonList.Items.IndexOf(YesNo_RadioButtonList.Items.FindByValue(values[2]));
        }
    }
```

Some additional info..

I've debugged using breakpoints and found that Password and Confirm Password are holding the correct text but the data does not get displayed in their respective text boxes. Where have i goofed up?

Comment: So i found that if i remove the TextMode="Password" property for the text box controls, the page works fine.